# Is it possible: Android to Blackberry application conversion

Tags: android, blackberry, android-emulator, blackberry-jde

I have an android application, I want that application to use in blackberry. Is there any way to convert android application to blackberry application?

Comment: You can wait for the rumored RIM migration to QNX, when it will support Android apps. :) On a more serious note, I ported in the other direction. I basically had to throw away all the UI code (keeping most of the design). You will also lilkely have trouble with the Java level, since BB has no generics (basically Java 1.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that i know of. But if you're developing from scratch you can try a cross platform mobile framework such as appcelerator phonegap or adobe air

If your application was build with phonegap then you're in luck. Your application was built using standard web technologies like HTML5 Javascript etc. The phonegamp software is a wrapper that lets you native api calls for your particular phone. All thats left to do is deploy to your targeted device.

The pages below show how it works and what oses are supported

http://www.phonegap.com/about

http://www.phonegap.com/features

Comment: My android application(which I haven't worked on) has been build by using phonegap, now does that build can be used in blackberry too?

Comment: it may not be as simple as recompiling for blackberry and it works, but thats the goal of phonegap. Its fairly new so there may be some issues but its better than trying to rewrite a native app.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean as a user with an Android app that you want to run on your BlackBerry, no.

If you are an Android developer, there will soon be an emulator (or as RIM calls it a player) that will allow Android applications to be repackaged (perhapse needing to be recompiled) to run on a PlayBook.

There is some speculation that the BlackBerry Tablet OS is the prototype for some future generation of BlackBerry handeld device OS. If this actually comes true then we can probably expect that the player, if successful, would also be available on that platform. But at this point that would be speculation.